# Running Mocha on windows for jsx test

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mocha.js

I'm trying to go through a tutorial on react/redux and I am running into an error when it comes to running unit tests with mocha.

when i run 'npm run test' i get the following error (which I suspect has to do with the path or the .jsx extensions).

```
17 error Windows_NT 6.3.9600
18 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\xenoputtss\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "test"
19 error node v5.1.0
20 error npm  v3.4.1
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error voting-client@1.0.0 test: `mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --require ./test/test_helper.js 'test/**/*.@(js|jsx)'`
22 error Exit status 255
23 error Failed at the voting-client@1.0.0 test script 'mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --require ./test/test_helper.js 'test/**/*.@(js|jsx)''.
23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the voting-client package,
23 error not with npm itself.
23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
23 error     mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --require ./test/test_helper.js 'test/**/*.@(js|jsx)'
23 error You can get their info via:
23 error     npm owner ls voting-client
23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

my package.json is setup like this for the scripts.

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --require ./test/test_helper.js 'test/**/*.@(js|jsx)'",
    "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch"
```

},

Answer (score 2):

Haha - I'm working on the same tutorial and ran into the same issue.

So Windows doesn't support UNIX-style globbing like that, but I did find a fix / workaround.

1) Use a BASH shell (i.e., Git Bash, CMDer, or cygwin)
2) Replace the single quotes around the glob w/ double quotes

```
"test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --require ./test/test_helper.js \"test/**/*.@(js|jsx)\""
```

That should run the tests on all *.js and *.jsx files. Tested it in Git Bash, CMDer, and cygwin.

Comment: I like the idea, but I'm not comfortable with installing another shell just to get a test to work.  

I should probably look up how the globbing works in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to skrillcosby for pointing out the specific part that was failing in the command.  I was able to correct the issue without installing other software.

The issue was of course that last part of the test command

```
'test/**/*.@(js|jsx)'
```

two issues with this are the | symbol and the @ symbol.  Replacing this text with the following corrects the issue.

```
test/**/*.js*
```

Yes, remove the quotes also.

Also, after discovering the fix I did a search on the tutorial i was working for and discovered that someone else mentioned the fix 2 months ago.  http://teropa.info/blog/2015/09/10/full-stack-redux-tutorial.html#comment-2264530944